# How to declare a content as linkable in Plone 5's TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, plone, plone-5.x

I know how to declare a content type as "linkable" in Plone 4 and now I want to do the same thing for Plone 5.

Any hints?

This is the code I'm working on: https://github.com/collective/collective.liveblog/pull/34/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no restriction in Plone 5, so any content type is linkable, there is nothing to configure (I have made the following test: I have created a new content type, I have created a new content with it, then I have edited the Plone front-page body text and I have added a link to my new content)

Comment: It's probably not a real problem, but it seems we are missing a black list in that way.